# What is the simplest data-structure here to provide needed amount of info?

Tags: c#, datetime, data-structures, calendar, scheduling

How would you **construct a data-structure** -represented as Schedule class below- which would give you enough information in order to provide your ExtensionMethod a simple and enough information so that it can set testResult_# variables.

**Note that** : I am not asking how to implement GetScheduleById(string) method but asking for defining the Schedule data-structure in aw way that it can be simple as much as possible by providing all the needed info to this method.

```
var datetimeUnderTest = DateTime.Now;
Schedule workingDaysSchedule = ScheduleRepository.GetScheduleById("dubaiWorkingDays");
Schedule workingHoursSchedule = ScheduleRepository.GetScheduleById("usaWorkingHours");
Schedule winterSchedule = ScheduleRepository.GetScheduleById("brasilWinter");
Schedule nightsInWeekendSchedule = ScheduleRepository.GetScheduleById("NightsInWeekends");
Schedule nightsInWeekDaysSchedule = ScheduleRepository.GetScheduleById("NightsInWeekDays");

// IsInSchedule is an Extension method on DateTime
bool testResult_0 = datetimeUnderTest.IsInSchedule(workingDaysSchedule ); 
bool testResult_1= datetimeUnderTest.IsInSchedule(workingHoursSchedule ); 
bool testResult_2 = datetimeUnderTest.IsInSchedule(winterSchedule); 
bool testResult_3 = datetimeUnderTest.IsInSchedule(nightsInWeekendSchedule ); 
bool testResult_4 = datetimeUnderTest.IsInSchedule(nightsInWeekDaysSchedule );
```

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like something that the **Specification pattern** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern may be able to help with. Define specifications for availability then pass a recipient into a specification to ascertain if they satisfy the specification i.e. they are available.

Comment: I assume this is most about finding a convenient way of defining a proper DataStructure that can carry enough info to help answering those questions.

Comment: essentially, yes. Could you elaborate on your question as I'm not 100% sure of what it is you're asking. Could you start with what the problem is and what you have so far?

Comment: I re-asked the question. I hope this time it is more clear.

Comment: Would a HashMap (or Dictionary) work for the ScheduleRepository? Where the key is the Id and the value is the Schedule. GetScheduleById would map to TryGetValue and IsInSchedule would map to containsKey.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that a `Schedule` is just a list of date/time ranges. Or, perhaps a set of time ranges in each of the 7 week days. For example, a `workingDaysSchedule` would probably consist of one entry for each day (Monday through Friday). That entry would be from 00:00 to 23:59:59.

`nightsInWeekendSchedule` would have entries for Friday and Saturday, whatever the night time hours are.

The simplest way to model it (not necessarily the most efficient), would be something like:

```
class TimeRange
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

class Schedule
{
    private List<List<TimeRange>> Days = new List<List<TimeRange>>
    {
        new List<TimeRange>(), // Sunday
        new List<TimeRange>(), // Monday
        // etc.
    };
    public Add(DayOfWeek day, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime);
    public Contains(DateTime test);
}
```

Given a `DateTime` value, you can find the day of week ([DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx)), and then do a linear search on the list of ranges for that day.

There are a few complications that you'll have to take into account. An 11:00 pm to 7:00 am shift on Friday, for example, will actually be two ranges: 11:00 pm to midnight on Friday, and then 12:01 am to 7:00 am on Saturday. Your code to add the range will have to split the range and add to both Friday and Saturday's schedule.

Or, you could avoid the complication of the `Add` method and just code the range using the collection initializer syntax.